# Android Studio Error/Warning : Cannot Find System Dns

Tags: android, resolution, android-virtual-device, dsn

I am using Android Studio 2.2 and when I try to do a trial run of hello world  program, I am facing the error "cannot find system dns servers! Name resolution will be disabled". Also am getting avd with blank screen. Can you help me to solve this issue?
Please Find the Image below:

Name Resolution - DNS Error
[image]

Use Host GPU not available
[image]

Comment: Please make sure that you are connected to internet. That should be the problem.

Comment: Thanks Singh for your comment! The error is gone now. But still blank screen is playing in Emulator. By the way cannt we run the android programs without internet connection?

Comment: I suggest that you verify the Android Studio installation on your machine. https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html ... see also: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html

Comment: Hi Kristoffer, i did it in the same way....so far it didnt work

Answer (score 1):

Change Graphics option from `Auto` to `Software-GLES2`.

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Try solved it by selecting "Use Host GPU" as the emulation option at the bottom of the "Create..." screen.

Comment: I have searched for the "use host GPU" in Android 2.2 avd.I could not find that one. Only we have Emulated Performance - Graphics option is there.I have added the image in main thread

Answer (score 0):

From me right click the AVD and "cold boot now" worked. Hope that helps